# ajax is not working in codeigniter, doesn't post or start the method in the controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to search for my problem, but didn't find anything, also can't debug this, I tried to put breakpoints in do_login method and `$("#frm_login").submit(function(event)`
it doesn't even get to it 
here it is the code for the **signin_view Ajax script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#frm_login").submit(function(event)
{
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo site_url('signin/do_login'); ?>',
type: 'POST',
data:{ username : $('#username').val(),password : $('#password').val()},
success:function(data) {
    if (data ==='logged_in')
    {
        alert("working");
    }
    else if(data === 'no')
    {
                    alert("problem");

    }
}
});
           });
                          });
```

and here it is the **form**

```
  <form id='frm_login' name='frm_login' action="#" >

                    <input type="text" id='username' name="username" size="15" placeholder="اسم المستخدم">                              

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="15" placeholder="كلمة المرور" >                              
                            <div id="message"> </div>   
                            <input type='submit' value="تسجيل الدخول">
    </form>
```

and this is **signin controller**

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class signin extends CI_Controller
{



function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index(){

$this->load->view('signin_view');
}

function do_login()
{
{$this->load->model("M_accces");

$POSTINGDATA = $this->input->post('username');
if(isset($POSTINGDATA))
{
$user = $this->m_access->check_user(
        $this->input->post('username'),
        md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );
if($user == '1') {
echo 'logged_in';
} else {
echo 'no';
    }
}
```

and here is the **M_accces model**

```
class M_access extends CI_Model {
public function check_user($username,$password) {
$this->query = $this->db->select('COUNT(*)')
    ->from('users')
    ->where(array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password))
    ->limit(1)->get();
return $this->query->row_array();
}
}
```

**the autoloaded**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','file','form','security');
```

Can any one help why it is not working ?

The page is just refreshing.
Thanks

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: please fix the question, controller quotation (grey background), so they won't down vote your question ....

Comment: Thanks Nassim, done editing

Comment: for your data, it should be `data:{ username : $('#username').val(),password : $('#password').val()},` Note *#* not dot for selector.you have id parameter for input. no class parameter mentioned.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `site_url('signin/do_login');`

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to load the model in the controller

```
$this->load->model("M_accces");
```

you can put it just after do_login() function/ method, or in the constructor

salam

Comment: thanks Nassim, although it didn't solve the problem as the debugger didn't got to the do login method but really thanks, I forgot to add it!
salam ^_^

Comment: if you upvote and / or accept my solution that will make my day hope that helps

Comment: lol ok bro no problem, then upvote it when you grow up a little , i will upvote your question, that will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the document ready function and drag your js function and place it after closing the form and it will work.
Note: Press f12 in your browser and select network and see if the request is successfully sent or not.

If request is successfully sent and the program is still not working , click on the request then preview you will see the error shown.

Comment: you mean start the script like this ?
$("#frm_login").submit(function(event)
and so on.... ? right ?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean, Make sure you put the function before closing your body tag .

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax Request has wrong selector used

```
$.ajax({
url: '<? echo site_url('signin/do_login'); ?>',
type: 'POST',
async : false,
// Note # selector.
data:{ username : $('#username').val(),password : $('#password').val()},
success:function(data) {
    if (data ==='logged_in')
    {
        alert("working");
    }
    else if(data === 'no')
    {
                    alert("problem");

    }
}
});
```

In your controller method check for **$POSTINGDATA** for empty value.

```
function do_login()
{
$POSTINGDATA = $this->input->post('username');
// check for empty. 
if(isset($POSTINGDATA) && !empty($POSTINGDATA))
{
$user = $this->m_access->check_user(
        $this->input->post('username'),
        md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );
if($user == '1') {
echo 'logged_in';
} else {
echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Comment: done, I think it solved many errors but still 
now I have this error in console 
1-Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
2-POST http://localhost/signin/do_login 500 (Internal Server Error)f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:4f.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ signin:18f.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3f.event.add.h.handle.i @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: @HeshamWatany Do you get alert after doing changes? For time being also try to remove `async : false,` and let me know what you get.

Comment: async solved the first error but still get nothing and have in consol this error ->
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: try to put `die;` after `echo` in controller.

Comment: try to call url directly form browser like **http://localhost/project/index.php/signin/do_login**

Comment: POST http://localhost/newsite/signin/do_login 500 (Internal Server Error)send @ jquery.min.js:4f.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ signin:18f.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3h.handle.i @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: @HeshamWatany try same after clearing your browser cache and cookies.